# Writing a knowledge base (KB) in propositional logic and converting the KB into conjunctive normal form

Tags: logic

If you walk your dog, he'll be happy. If you don't walk him, he'll chew up your furniture. If he's happy or if he chews your furniture, he'll mess up your apartment. If he messes up your apartment, you'll be annoyed. 
Does your dog mess up your apartment?
Are you annoyed at him?

1. Write the knowledge base given above in propositional logic.
2. Convert the knowledge base into conjunctive normal form.
3. Use resolution to prove by contradiction that your dog made a mess. Connect the two clauses to a new clause that the can be collapsed into (see the example figure).

Example figure: [image: Example figure]